# jquery & html form - pass jsvariable

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Currently I've got a set of images in a list:

```
<div id="holiday">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="images/stationery/christmas.jpg" width="68" height="80" /></li>
     <li><img src="images/stationery/easter.jpg" width="68" height="80" /></li>
     <li><img src="images/stationery/hannukah.jpg" width="68" height="80" /></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

When the user clicks one of the images, the background of this div changes:

```
var switchfg = jQuery('#preview');
var switchbg = jQuery('#holiday img');

switchbg.on("click", function() {
var img3 = $(this).attr('src');
switchfg.css('background', "url("+img3+")");
var stationery=img3;
alert(stationery);
```

The variable stationery now holds the value I want to pass via the form, which is POSTed. Right before the submit button I tried to add the contents of the variable stationery, but it only passes the word "stationery."

```
$('form.general').append("<input type='hidden' name='stationery' value="stationery" />");
```

How can I get this value passed via POST to be submitted into a db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function you have to concatenate the variable stationery, in your mode you assign the value "stationery" and not the variable.
Obviuos you have to put this code in the function when you assign the value stationery and not in other part or you can in this case use global variable

Try this code instead of yours:

```
$('form.general').append("<input type='hidden' name='stationery' value='"+stationery+"' />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from

```
$('form.general').append("<input type='hidden' name='stationery' value="stationery" />");
```

to

```
$('form.general').append("<input type='hidden' name='stationery' value='" + stationery + "' />");
```

two string a and b are concatenated in javascript using `a + b`.